# How to get only hyperlinks by removing its tags and special characters?

Tags: java, html, hyperlink, tags, jsoup

I want to get only:

```
http://tamilblog.ishafoundation.org/nalvazhvu/vazhkai/
```

and not all these:

```
<a href="http://tamilblog.ishafoundation.org/nalvazhvu/vazhkai/"></a>
```

I just want to apply this to my loop (section):

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class NewClassssssss {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Document doc =  Jsoup.connect("http://tamilblog.ishafoundation.org/page/3//").get();

        Elements section = doc.select("section#content");
        Elements article = section.select("article");
        Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");

        for (Element a : section) {
            //   System.out.println("Title : \n" + a.select("a").text());
            System.out.println(a.select("a[href]"));
        }

        System.out.println(links);
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(a.select("a[href]").attr("href"))` should do what you want.

Comment: not clear what you want to Say . you want to remove Some Text From URL ? . Fancy Class Name

Comment: The output of this code is like <a href="http://dhyanalinga.org/">Dhyanalinga</a>
<a href="http://lingabhairavi.org/">Linga Bhairavi</a>  I wantto remove those characters and want output like this "http://dhyanalinga.org" "http://lingabhairavi.org/"

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/2333222/suboptimal  I am getting only one link as output.I want to extract all a[href] from that Section#content tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems in the code:

#### 1. Invalid search scope

```
Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
```

The above line gets all links from the whole document instead of the articles only.

#### 2. Invalid node used in loop

```
for (Element a : section) {
   // ...
}
```

The above for loop works on the sections instead of the links.

#### 3. Repetitive calls to `select` method

```
Elements section = doc.select("section#content");
Elements article = section.select("article");
Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
```

It's not necessary to perform a selection for each node in the hierarchy. Jsoup can navigate through it for you. Those three lines can be replaced with one line:

```
Elements links = doc.select("section#content article a");
```

---

**SAMPLE CODE**

Here is a sample code resuming all the three precedent points:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://tamilblog.ishafoundation.org/nalvazhvu/vazhkai/").get();

for (Element a : doc.select("section#content article a")) {
    System.out.println("Title : \n" + a.text());
    System.out.println(a.absUrl("href")); // absUrl is used here for *always* having absolute urls.
}
```

**OUTPUT**

    Title :

```
http://tamilblog.ishafoundation.org/kalyana-parisaga-isha-kaattupoo/
Title : 
இதயம் பேசுகிறது
http://tamilblog.ishafoundation.org/isha-pakkam/idhyam-pesugiradhu/
Title : 
வாழ்க்கை
http://tamilblog.ishafoundation.org/nalvazhvu/vazhkai/
Title : 
கல்யாணப் பரிசாக ஈஷா காட்டுப்பூ…
http://tamilblog.ishafoundation.org/kalyana-parisaga-isha-kaattupoo/
... (truncated for brievety)
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Elements links = document.select("a[href]");             
for (Element link : links) {
    System.out.println(link.attr("abs:href"));             
}
```