# How to scrape the hyperlinks from a webpage using JSOUP

Tags: java, html

When I am scraping with the following code it does not show any element within body tag, but in manually checking with view-source it shows the elements in body. How to scrape the hyperlinks in the following URL?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, IOException {
       String search_url = "http://www.manta.com/search?search=geico";
       Document doc = Jsoup.connect(search_url).userAgent("Mozilla").get();
       System.out.println(doc);
       Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
       System.out.println(links);
       for (Element a : links) {
           System.out.println(a);
           String linkhref=a.attr("href");
           System.out.println(linkhref);
         }
   }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile System.out.println("url is:"+url); should be System.out.println("url is:"+search_url); once this is updated it works

Comment: Can you please check the remaining code

Comment: read my comment once updated it works. And you can try it by yourself

Comment: If your code does not provide the result you expect, than you should provide an example what is missed. As @JEY said, your code `System.out.println(linkhref);` returns the link. You could also check the answer to this post [how-to-get-only-hyperlinks-by-removing-its-tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34629413/how-to-get-only-hyperlinks-by-removing-its-tags-and-special-characters-in-java)